# How to Clear Bindable Property Warnings in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have created custom radio button for android by using custom renderer as follows. The below warnings are shown in output window. I have tried many ways and reffered many sites but I don't get any clear solution to fix this warning. Can anybody give suggestion without changing the nuget version.

```cs
    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create<BindableRadioGroup, IEnumerable>
                (o => o.ItemsSource, default(IEnumerable), propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

        public static BindableProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<BindableRadioGroup, 
                int>(o => o.SelectedIndex, default(int), BindingMode.TwoWay, 
                propertyChanged: OnSelectedIndexChanged);

 public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }


        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
        }


 private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IEnumerable oldvalue, IEnumerable newvalue)
        {
            var radButtons = bindable as BindableRadioGroup;

            radButtons.rads.Clear();
            radButtons.Children.Clear();
            if (newvalue != null)
            {

                int radIndex = 0;
                foreach (var item in newvalue)
                {
                    var rad = new CustomRadioButton();
                    rad.Text = item.ToString();
                    rad.Id = radIndex;

                    rad.CheckedChanged += radButtons.OnCheckedChanged;

                    radButtons.rads.Add(rad);

                    radButtons.Children.Add(rad);
                    radIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

 private static void OnSelectedIndexChanged(BindableObject bindable, int oldvalue, int newvalue)
        {
            if (newvalue == -1) return;

            var bindableRadioGroup = bindable as BindableRadioGroup;

            foreach (var rad in bindableRadioGroup.rads)
            {
                if (rad.Id == bindableRadioGroup.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    rad.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

[Displayed Warning Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niLr2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The warning message clearly states that generic version of BindableProperty.Create is deprecated.

Use the non generic version, here is an example based on your `ItemsSourceProperty`:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: nameof(ItemsSource),
                returnType: typeof(IEnumerable)),
                declaringType: typeof(BindableRadioGroup),
                propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);
```

So just rewrite your BindableProperty declarations or suppress the warnings (not recommended). 
If you are still not sure how to do this, please refer to the [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Creating_a_Property).

Comment: When I use like this, I got the following error... public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(CustomRadioButton), 
                                   null, propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged));  ..... foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumetator'

Comment: I have changed as your suggestion but the error is not clear.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: The exception is not related to your original answer. What you could to is to explicitly set the type of your IEnumerable or replace IEnumeralable by List. However, you didn't share the full code of your control and without knowing where exactly (which line) you get the exception could be hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @EvZ, I have cleared that warning like this,

```
 public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(ItemsSource), 
          returnType: typeof(IEnumerable), declaringType: typeof(BindableRadioGroup), 
          propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);


private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
    var radButtons = bindable as BindableRadioGroup;

    radButtons.rads.Clear();
    radButtons.Children.Clear();
    if (newvalue != null)
    {
        var value = newvalue as IEnumerable;
        int radIndex = 0;
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            var rad = new CustomRadioButton();
            rad.Text = item.ToString();
            rad.Id = radIndex;

            rad.CheckedChanged += radButtons.OnCheckedChanged;

            radButtons.rads.Add(rad);

            radButtons.Children.Add(rad);
            radIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```